# Python-Pandas doesn't read entire csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I want to read a csv-file (34cols, ~1000rows) using pandas.
Thats what im doing so far:

```
folder = sys.argv[1]
delimChar = "\\"
files = os.listdir(folder)


pathToFile = folder+delimChar+files[0]
df = pd.read_csv(pathToFile,sep=",")
print(df.head())
```

Here is the output from pandas

```
           A         ...   AH
0          0.001869  ...   0.0
1          0.003737  ...   0.0
2          0.005606  ...   0.0
3          0.008030  ...   0.0
4          0.011637  ...   0.0

[5 rows x 34 columns]
```

For some reason it only reads the first couple of lines.
Why is pandas stopping after the first 5 rows ?

Comment: Hey.. df.head() is subsetting the first few lines of the data frame, you can do print(df) or df.shape to see the dimensions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the docs for `DataFrame.head(self: ~FrameOrSeries, n: int = 5) → ~FrameOrSeries` [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.head.html). It says:

> This function returns the first n rows for the object based on position. It is useful for quickly testing if your object has the right type of data in it.

So `df` already holds those ~1000 rows but `print(df.head())` only shows the first five of them.